# Selenium-webdriver Firefox issue windows 7

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am running Selenium Webdriver locally on my windows home server (windows 7 professional actually) which logs to a site and sends some emails. It's a java program with a single thread running.

I can see Firefox opening up just fine when running through Eclipse and follow the clicks etc as it logs on without problems.

I have set up a Task Scheduler task to start it up every morning though and run the jar. The program runs fine but when Firefox opens it is almost invisible, I can see the grey frames of it but everything else is transparent and invisible and if you drag something in front of it the graphics get stuck.

When clicking on Properties on Task manager I can see that it started with firefox.exe - foreground whereas when I open Firefox normally it says -browser.

The program still does what it should do, it's just Firefox is not visible at all when running through java -jar X.jar etc.

Any ideas why?

Windows 7 Professional

WebDriver 2.32

Firefox 21

I suspect it has something to do with the anonymous Firefox Profiles created each time firefox runs. I usually delete them from Temp once a week.

P.S No idea if it matters but server is headless and I am accessing it through TeamViewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by deleting firefox profiles and loading from scratch. Weird, not sure yet what caused this and if it happens again.

Perhaps I will create a specific firefox profile and use instead of a anonymous one created each time.